# How work DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri) in samsung sgs8 android 7?

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-mobile

I have next simple code for getting path for image file:

```
if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex())
                    .dropLastWhile {
                        it.isEmpty()
                    }
                    .toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]

                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + split[1])
                }
            }
```

But in my samsung galaxy s 8 with android 7 `DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)` return strange data, look like this:

```
9016-4EF8:DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0908.jpg
```

and this is not `primary` in first place. In other phones return correct value. And if hardcoded getting this value next: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + split[1]` - return null.

Is there a problem? maybe I missed something from the new Android API or Samsung as it trims its functionality?

Comment: It some times Samsung specific, but I am not sure in this case because I haven't used this API in a while. Someone will be able to confirm.

Comment: @dazza5000 in sgs 6 android 7workflow is correcly. very strange...

Comment: Did `DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)` returns a valid id in Android Oreo?